# Samba share - follows symlink but already in local path

Tags: symlink, samba, shared-folders

I just faced a problem which I couldn't find anywhere (ex. samba documentation).

I have a samba share on server1, and this share mounted to server2. server1's share is a symlink to `/var/container/db`.

The problem is that when I try to open this symlinked folder from server2, it shows my local files on server2, since the path `/var/container/db`exists on my server2.

What can cause this problem, and what's the solution for it?

Both server running on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

If you share a symlink between Unix-like hosts, the system that mounts the share will interpret the symlink according to its own filesystem tree. That's just how Unix-style symlinks work.

If the share on server 1 includes the thing you want the symlink to point to, you could use a *relative* symlink instead of an absolute one.

For example, if your samba share on server1 is `/var` and it's mounted on server2 as `/server1var`, and the symlink is located on server1 as `/var/some/directory/link-to-db`, your current symlink would be made like this:

```
server1# ln -s /var/container/db /var/some/directory/link-to-db
```

Instead, you could do it like this:

```
server1# cd /var/some/directory
server1# ln -s ../../container/db link-to-db
```

---

If the database on server1 is not within the Samba share, then you would need the Samba server parameter `wide links = yes`. This would make server1 follow the symlink and provide access to server1's `/var/container/db` instead of just passing the syml

However, if the server is running on default settings, it also has `unix extensions = yes` enabled by default - which will disable `wide links` if the client is a Unix-like system (as in your case).

However, by setting `allow insecure wide links = yes`, you could allow the `wide links` parameter to work even when `unix extensions` are in effect on the share connection - **but this is not recommended because it is not secure.** The administrator on server1 would lose control of what is shared and what is not, because clients could attempt to gain access to any file outside the Samba share by just creating a suitable symbolic link on the share if it's writeable - and then it would be just a matter of whether the user account used on the connection has permissions to read the file or not.

Basically, `allow insecure wide links` + `wide links` + `unix extensions` + a client-writable share is practically equivalent to just sharing `/` with Samba. Not recommended.